# Select all dates from a given date range having to and from dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a report where I want the calendar of all of the days in an year who must be printed in a sequential manner i.e. sort by dates.

I have two tables, one who has holiday(s) details and the other has the standard in and out time of working days.

Here are the column details of both of the tables :

**Working_hour_parameter** : `Dt(Date),STD_INTIME ,STD_OUTTIME`

**Holidays** : `from_dt, to_dt ,holiday_type, remarks`

Example : If I pass the date range from 1st november to 5 november and let say 2nd,3rd november is holiday, it must return result as :

```
From date      To date      std_intime   std_outtime  remarks
-------        --------      --------   -------       ------ 
1st-Nov        1st-Nov      09:00        17:30        working day

2nd-Nov        3rd-Nov      (null)      (null)         holiday

4th-Nov        5th-Nov      09:00        17:30        working day
```

The problem is, one of the table has date range columns i.e. to and from dates and the other table is based on single date.

How is it possible?

Can anybody help me please?

Snapshot of tables :

[image: working hour parameter table]

[image: Holiday table]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Like a screenshot of the table or something like that

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh i've placed the snapshots

Comment: oh dear, images of data, so frustrating.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Why is `1st-NOV`, a working day in one row and `4th-NOV` , `5th-NOV` - 2 working days also in one row

Comment: @KaushikNayak this is how I want the output because they both are working days. this is same as in 2nd-3rd november which is holiday in one row

Answer (score 0):

The general solution for this problem is to generate a row for each date needed which can be done with `connect by rownum` (Oracle specific) or a variety of other means such as a recursive `common table expression` (many dbs). You might might even consider creating a "calendar table" if you need to do this on a very regular basis. e.g.

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT to_date('2017-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + rownum - 1 dt
    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366
    )
WHERE dt < to_date('2018-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Once you have the dates in rows, left join both sets of your data to those dates and the job is done.

```
select cal.dt, wp.*, h.*
from (
    SELECT to_date('2017-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + rownum - 1 dt
    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 36
     ) cal
left join Working_hour_parameter wp on cal.dt = wp.Dt
left join Holidays h on cal.dt between h.from_dt and h.to_dt 
WHERE cal.dt < to_date('2018-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

### ----

To also propose a way to summaize this per ay data, `first_value()` and `last_value() are used to forms "islands" for grouping the ranges.

available as a demo at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ad3c/1)

```
CREATE TABLE WORKING_HOUR_PARAMETER
    (DT timestamp, STD_INTIME varchar2(5), STD_OUTTIME varchar2(5))
;

INSERT ALL
    INTO WORKING_HOUR_PARAMETER ("DT", "STD_INTIME", "STD_OUTTIME")
         VALUES ('01-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM', '09:00', '17:30')
    INTO WORKING_HOUR_PARAMETER ("DT", "STD_INTIME", "STD_OUTTIME")
         VALUES ('04-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM', '09:00', '17:30')
    INTO WORKING_HOUR_PARAMETER ("DT", "STD_INTIME", "STD_OUTTIME")
         VALUES ('05-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM', '09:00', '17:30')
    INTO WORKING_HOUR_PARAMETER ("DT", "STD_INTIME", "STD_OUTTIME")
         VALUES ('06-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM', '09:00', '17:30')
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE TABLE HOLIDAYS
    (FROM_DT timestamp, TO_DT timestamp, HOLIDAY_TYPE varchar2(8), REMARKS varchar2(12))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO HOLIDAYS ("FROM_DT", "TO_DT", "HOLIDAY_TYPE", "REMARKS")
         VALUES ('02-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM', '03-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM', 'whatever', 'avagoodbreak')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
         min(dt) span_from
       , max(dt) span_to
       , std_intime
       , std_outtime
       , from_dt hol_start
       , to_dt   hol_to
       , fval1   first_value
       , lval1   last_value
from (
    select cal.dt, h.FROM_DT, h.TO_DT, wp.std_intime, wp.std_outtime
    , first_value(FROM_DT ignore nulls) over(order by cal.dt rows between current row and unbounded following) fval1
    , last_value(TO_DT ignore nulls) over(order by cal.dt) lval1
    from (
        SELECT to_timestamp('2017-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + rownum - 1 dt
        FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 36
         ) cal
    left join Working_hour_parameter wp on cal.dt = wp.Dt
    left join Holidays h on cal.dt between h.from_dt and h.to_dt 
    WHERE cal.dt < to_date('2017-01-07','yyyy-mm-dd') 
    )
group by
         std_intime
       , std_outtime
       , from_dt
       , to_dt
       , fval1
       , lval1
order by 1, 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ad3c/1/0)**:

```
|            SPAN_FROM |              SPAN_TO | STD_INTIME | STD_OUTTIME |             HOL_START |                HOL_TO |           FIRST_VALUE |            LAST_VALUE |
|----------------------|----------------------|------------|-------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z |      09:00 |       17:30 |                (null) |                (null) | 2017-01-02 00:00:00.0 |                (null) |
| 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-03T00:00:00Z |     (null) |      (null) | 2017-01-02 00:00:00.0 | 2017-01-03 00:00:00.0 | 2017-01-02 00:00:00.0 | 2017-01-03 00:00:00.0 |
| 2017-01-04T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-06T00:00:00Z |      09:00 |       17:30 |                (null) |                (null) |                (null) | 2017-01-03 00:00:00.0 |
```

Comment: I agree with the technique but it looks like you'll need to do some extra work, perhaps using a partition that looks at the "holiday" or "working" status of the previous row (order by date) and increment a number if it has changed, then this can be grouped and the min and max date taken from the group, because the result has to have date ranges that say when a person is on holiday or in work, not a day by day list of whether that day is a work or holiday.

Comment: I've tried the following query : SELECT to_date('01-NOV-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') dt
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366
WHERE dt < to_date('30-NOV-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') , but there's a sql command not properly ended error

Comment: Change it to `SELECT to_date('01-NOV-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') + rownum dt FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366 ` the where clause is not needed as the query will only generate 366 rows. Also it was missing a bit to add the rownum to the date, so it generated 366 identical dates

Comment: sorry, that script snippet now runs, have been doing this amongst a bunch of other stuff. but I'm not trying to write the whole query really, giving you direction on how it may be solved.

Comment: the point raised by @CaiusJard is true, once you have every date available, then you need to summarize it.

Comment: Might it be easier to convert the work table to a range representation and then just union it to the holiday table , ordering by date ?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes it will be easier, let me try it

Comment: @Used_By_Already how can I pass the to and from dates in this query  select holiday_frmdt,holiday_todt,
(
SELECT * from (
    SELECT to_date(h.HOLIDAY_FRMDT,'DD-MON-YYYY') + rownum dt
    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366
    )
WHERE dt < to_date(h.HOLIDAY_TODT,'DD-MON-YYYY')
) dt from olpcdc.holidays h

Comment: pass what to what? I don't know what you mean. Why not setup a small http://sqlfiddle.com? then this would be easier to follow from afar. (*That's why images of data are such a pain* utterly unusable.)

Comment: @Used_By_Already pass from date in the query where range of date is to be started. it should be taken from the holiday_frmdt column of holiday table

Comment: that url has `WHERE cal.dt < to_date(h.HOLIDAY_TODT,'yyyy-mm-dd') ` but **h.HOLIDAY_TODT** does not exist. did you mean **h.to_dt** Plus if that intended column is already a date you do not need to use to_date() - was that your question?

Comment: I added a method to summarize, I hope this helps resolve any remaining issues